# Audio coming through laptop speakers instead of headphones Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones

Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 in dual-boot with Windows 10. I have no issues with plugging in my headphones and having sound coming out through those instead of my laptop's speakers on Windows but I can't seem to be able to do the same in Ubuntu. In pavucontrol it says "Line Out" is unplugged for some reason. Anyone got any ideas as to what I should do? Install the realtek drivers for linux or something of the sort?

Using an Asus ROG G751JL and whenever i plug in my headphones in Windows I get a popup from the High Definition Audio software asking me to confirm which device I plugged in.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.